# Order by in sub query using oracle

Tags: oracle, subquery

I tried to get value from sub query after ordering the records of it but  the following occurred when execute the query :
**ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis**

The Query is :

```
select S.value , nvl((select D.value  from D
                join  T on D.subID = t.SubID
                where  D.subid2 = s.subid2 and t.subid3 = s.subid3    and rownum = 1 order by t.id),0 ) value

from   S
```

Comment: Tables represent unordered data sets. A subquery result is a table. Fot this reason it makes no sense to have an `ORDER BY` in a subquery, and it is even forbidden to end a subquery with an `ORDER BY` clause (there is one exception to that rule in Oracle, but let's neglect that). Sorting the results wouln't make sense any way, because with `rownum = 1` you select a single row. If you sorted a list consisting of one row, you would end up with the same single row of course.

Comment: If rownum = 1 was meant to happen after the order by in your subquery, so as to get the d.value for the lowest t.id, you could change `and rownum = 1 order by t.id` to `order by t.id fetch first row only`, which is allowed, because `ORDER BY` is not the last clause in the query and hence not ordering the results, but merely preparing the intermediate result set for the fetch clause. Another option is Oracle's `KEEP FIRST` for which you'd remove `and rownum = 1 order by t.id` altogether and replace `select D.value` by `select min(d.value) keep (dense_rank first order by t.id)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have `ORDER BY`  clause in a subquery.

See if something like this helps: use a CTE (as it *looks* somewhat nicer; could be a *normal* subquery, if you want) which *calculates* ordinal number for all rows, sorted by `t.id` column value. In outer (main) query, select row whose `rn = 1` (which should *act* just like your `ORDER BY t.id` + `rownum = 1`).

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT s.VALUE s_value,
              d.VALUE d_value,
              ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY t.id) rn
         FROM d
              JOIN t ON d.subid = t.subid
              JOIN s
                 ON     s.subid2 = d.subid2
                    AND s.subid3 = t.subid3)
SELECT s_value, NVL (d_value, 0) d_value
  FROM temp
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Oracle 12c or higher, you can use the `FETCH FIRST...` clause.

```sql
SELECT S.VALUE,
       NVL ((  SELECT D.VALUE
                 FROM D JOIN T ON D.subID = t.SubID
                WHERE D.subid2 = s.subid2 AND t.subid3 = s.subid3
             ORDER BY t.id
                FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY),
            0)    VALUE
  FROM S
```